# Scraping @Type from HTML Script into a csv file using pandas

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-science

I am trying web scraping for the first time and I am having a lot of trouble especially because the website I am supposed to use tries its best to block scraping libraries. I downloaded the HTML code, but the data I want to collect to make a csv file is not in tags (like div, li,...). It is as @type showing a dictionary. I need to make a dataset with columns showing those in the dictionary (Rating Value, Author, URL, and description). The HTML source code I downloaded is attached below. Would appreciate your help!
[image: Example of one of the review pages code]

and here is the code I used to scrape it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
import codecs
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#import nltk
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#from tensorflow import keras
os.system('cls')


PATH = "C:\\Users\\HCES\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
i=1
driver.get("https://www.zomato.com/beirut/divvy-ashrafieh/reviews?page= {}&sort=dd&filter=reviews-dd".format(i))
page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source,"lxml")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import json
import re

import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0'
}


def main(url, page):
    params = {
        'page': page,
        'sort': 'dd',
        'filter': 'reviews-dd'
    }
    r = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
    match = re.search(r'\.parse\((.*)\)', r.text).group(1)
    goal = json.loads(json.loads(match))

    print(goal.keys())


main('https://www.zomato.com/beirut/divvy-ashrafieh/reviews', 1)
```

Output:

```
dict_keys(['pages', 'blogData', 'pageUrlMappings', 'careers', 'allJobs', 'department', 'aboutus', 'sneakpeek', 'apiState', 'entities', 'user', 'uiLogic', 'location', 'gAds', 'footer', 'langKeys', 'deviceSpecificInfo', 'pageBlockerInfo', 'fullPageAds', 'networkState', 'fetchConfigs', 'hrefLangInfo', 'pageConfig', 'partnershipLoginModal', 'partnershipLoginOptionModal', 'doesNotDeliverModal', 'backButton'])
```

Comment: This is a great step towards the goal, but there is not a key for the reviews or rating which is what I am looking  to get

Comment: @Jana.k are you aware it's nested dict!

Answer (score 1):

From the `soup`, you can select the `<script>` that has the text

> window.**PRELOADED_STATE** = .....

and

- Extract the string (which is in JSON format) by doing some string manipulations like *stripping* off unnecessary data
- Convert that to JSON format using `json` module
- Extract the data you need from the JSON.

*In my code, `x` refers to the above mentioned `<script>` element*

```
import json
x = x.lstrip('window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = JSON.parse("')
x = x.rstrip('");')

json_string = json.loads(x)
```

`json_string` is in JSON format and you can pull the data.