# Extract dictionaries from HTML scraped text

Tags: python, json, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I extracted the HTML code from a website (scraping restaurant reviews) and I ended up with the part I need in the form of a dictionary. I managed to get all the scripts with the same  tag using the code below, but I do not know how to filter out the tags to get only the one with the reviews in it and convert it into dictionaries and eventually to csv file.

This is the (most of the) script tag that I need to keep:
[image]

This is the code I used to download all the HTML codes for the reviews pages and store them in text files:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
import codecs
import os
os.system('cls')


PATH = "C:\\Users\\HCES\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)


for i in range(1,450):
    completeName = os.path.join('C:\\Users\\HCES\\Desktop\\jana\\scraped files', ("index{}.txt").format(i))
    file_object = codecs.open(completeName, "w", "utf-8")
    driver.get("https://www.zomato.com/beirut/divvy-ashrafieh/reviews?page={}&sort=dd&filter=reviews-dd".format(i))
    file_object.write(driver.page_source)
    print("Page {} is written.".format(i))

driver.quit()
```

This is the code I used to print out only the script tags:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import codecs
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd

for x in range(1,2):
    revCode = open("index{}.txt".format(x), "r", encoding="utf8")
    content = revCode.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')
    for script_tag in soup.find_all('script'):
        print(script_tag.text, script_tag.next_sibling)
```

Your help is very much appreciated as I need this for work

Comment: I think you are wasting other times as you yourself is not sure what you are looking for! [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68573614/7658985) you received an answer for the same site mentioned and even you didn't care about [responding-back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68571722/scraping-type-from-html-script-into-a-csv-file-using-pandas#comment121200402_68573614). be informed that `Stack Overflow!` community is not a code writing service. with that said, please check [ask]

Comment: Hello! please calm down, the reason I rephrased the question and asked it in a different way was because the solutions to the other question did not work.

Comment: Also, in my previous question, I asked how to extract the script tag. In this question, I already did that and I asked how to filter them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `json` library to get the data inside tag in json format:

```
import json
...

data = soup.find('script', {"type": "application/ld+json"})
json_data = json.loads(data.string)
```

Now you can access any value with given key.